# No icon showing up for firefox installed with tar.bz2 package in /opt/firefox

Tags: gnome, firefox, icons

I'm not using snap version of firefox on a Ubuntu 22.04 box.
Instead, I'm installing the tar.bz2 package downloaded from ftp.mozilla.org in /opt.

I've created a desktop integration file in /usr/share/applications with this content :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Firefox Web Browser
Comment=Browse the World Wide Web
GenericName=Web Browser
Keywords=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer
Exec=firefox %u
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=/opt/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default256.png
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xml;application/rss+xml;application/rdf+xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;x-scheme-handler/chrome;video/webm;application/x-xpinstall;
StartupNotify=true
```

I also created a link from /usr/bin/firefox to /opt/firefox/firefox.

In Ubuntu 22.04 desktop, searching for firefox shows the application but the firefox icon is not correctly displayed.

Any hint really appreciated as I'm struggling on this for several weeks now.

Regards,
José.

Comment: Copying desktop integration file to /usr/local/share/applications as suggested by this page : https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux#w_system-firefox-installation-for-advanced-users does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Xubuntu uses XFCE, not gnome.
When the firefox icon did not appear on my Xubuntu system, I did the following:

1. install menulibre package
2. Right click on the whisker menu at upper left
3. Edit Applications
4. Expand the area involved (in this case, it was the internet portion)
5. Click on the application icon (firefox), be sure hide from menu is not selected

Comment: Thank you for this hint. But I'm looking for something more scriptable in ordre to create some specific Ansible playbook/role in order to automate the installation of firefox on a bunch of workstations.